# Laravel Mailgun send two mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, mailgun

When the user of my website used the contact form, i want send a mail with the confirmation to the user and send to me other message with the created ticket.

I´m using Laravel 5.2 + Mailgun

But only sent the last mail to my email hello@frikinow.com, the user confirmation email is not sent.

Laravel not returns any error. This is my code:

```
// for the client mail
                Mail::send('emails.success_email', ['name' => Input::get('nombre'), 'content' => $content], function ($message)
                {
                    $message->subject('FrikiNow ha recibido su consulta');

                    $message->from('hello@frikinow.com', 'FrikiNow Support');

                    $message->to(Input::get('email'));

                });

                // for me
                Mail::send('emails.ticket_email', ['email'=> Input::get('email'),'name' => Input::get('nombre'), 'content' => Input::get('mensaje'),'mobile_phone' =>Input::get('telefono')], function ($message)
                {
                    $message->subject('Ticket de Cliente: '.Input::get('asunto'));

                    $message->from('hello@frikinow.com', Input::get('nombre'));

                    $message->to('hello@frikinow.com');

                });
```

How I can send two different emails at once?

Answer (score 0):

You may add **CC** header

Im not full aware of MailGun API, but you can try this:

```
$message->cc('email@example.com'); //Copy of the message goes to this email
```